# OpenCV color detection without knowing colors a priori

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I'd like to draw bounding boxes around some color blobs, whose color I don't know beforehand. The images look like this:
[image]

every color in the scene represents a different object. I already tried findContours on the grayscale version of the image, however the contours obtained that way encompass multiple objects if they overlap. My wish would be to obtain the contours for individual objects, or multiple contours for an object if it is divided by another object in the scene. Is there a way to achieve this in OpenCV?
Thank you very much for your attention and time!

EDIT: as suggested, here my code

```
img = cv2.imread(img_path)

imgray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

kernel = np.ones((5,5), np.uint8)

im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(imgray, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

bboxes = []

for c in contours:
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    M = cv2.moments(c)
    if M["m00"]:
        cx = int(M['m10']/M['m00'])
        cy = int(M['m01']/M['m00'])
        area = cv2.contourArea(c)
        if area >= 25:
            colorHash = img[cy, cx]
            bboxes.append((Box(Point(x, y), Point(x+w, y+h)), colorHash, area))
            cv2.drawContours(img, [c], -1, (0, 0, 255), 1)

cv2.imshow("Image", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)   

return bboxes, contours
```

Here an image of the problem I'm trying to solve (marked blue, contours are red, the objects should have individual contours)

[image]

Comment: If the objects' colors are different, you can treat each color component as independent obj.

Answer (score 0):

You can raster scan the HSV color space of image and classify each pixel based on its hue value considering certain hue range.
After that mask the image using different hue value classes and hence segment each individual object of different colors.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! I already have such a solution working, however I wanted to improve upon it by getting individual bounding boxes in the case when an object is divided by something else in the image (for example when occluded, an arm being visible to the left of the occluder and the rest of the body to the right of it). In this case I wanted individual bounding boxes for the non-contiguous parts of the objects. I was hoping there was a comfortable solution to do this in openCV

Comment: In case of non contiguous object(multiple parts with same hue value) you will get multiple connected components in the hue based masked image, so you can merge those connected component's bounding boxes to get a single bounding box.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please post your code also so that we can see where the error is or give better suggestions to your method.
2. The following code draws the contours for individual objects in the image:

`

```
# -i : image path

# import stuff
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2

# Construct argument 
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument( "-i", "--image", required = True, help = "Path to the image")
ap.add_argument("-t", "--threshold", type = int, default = 100, help = "Enter threshold value")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# load image / grayscale
image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
print (image.shape)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

kernel = np.ones((5,5), np.uint8)
# blur the image for a mask
img = cv2.erode(gray, kernel, iterations=1)
img = cv2.dilate(img, kernel, iterations=1)
blurred = cv2.blur(img, (3,3))

# Threshold image to segment the objects
# requires grayscale image
methods = [
    ("THRESH_BINARY", cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    #("THRESH_BINARY_INV", cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
    ]

# loop for each threshold method
# (T, threshImage) = cv2.threshold(src, thresh, maxval, type)
for (threshName, threshMethod) in methods:
    (T, threshImage) = cv2.threshold(blurred, args["threshold"], 255, threshMethod)
    cv2.namedWindow(threshName,cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    cv2.resizeWindow(threshName, 600,600)
    cv2.imshow(threshName, threshImage)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

# # Adaptive thresholding
# adaptiveThresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blurred, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 4)

# Crop target image using thresh as mask
masked = cv2.bitwise_and(gray, gray, mask = threshImage)
# cv2.imshow("Mased Image", masked)
# cv2.waitKey(0)

# find contours
(_, cnts, _) = cv2.findContours(masked.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
print (" No. of Contours ={}".format(len(cnts)))

# draw the contours on top of the original image
drops = image.copy()
cv2.drawContours(drops, cnts, -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
cv2.namedWindow("Contours",cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.resizeWindow("Contours", 600,600)
cv2.imshow("Contours", drops)
cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.imwrite('contours.png',drops)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have edited the question to provide my code.

Answer (score 0):

Two approaches:

- use the contouring method as you did and keep the color of the blobs (any pixel from the outline), as well as the bounding boxes. Then merge the bounding boxes of the same color. This is conveniently done with the help of a dictionary of bounding boxes indexed by color.
- scan the image, starting with an empty dictionary. Every time you meet a non-black pixel, lookup its color and create or update the bounding box.

Note that there is no need of converting to another color system, keep the raw RGB.